# Nagata rings: localization and finite algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, local-rings

A Nagata (pseudo-geometric) ring is a Noetherian ring $R$, such that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is Japanese (N-2) for every prime $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq R$.

Matsumura claims in his book "Commutative Algebra" that

> If $R$ is a Nagata ring then any localization or $R$ and any finite $R$-algebra are again Nagata.

Similarly, Nagata writes in his book "Local Rings":

> If $R$ is a Nagata ring, then every homomorphic image
>   of $R$, every ring of quotients of $R$, and every ring which is a finite module
>   over $R$ are Nagata rings.

Both of these claims are not proven in the books and I would like to see a proof, at least of Matsumura's statement. So I would really appreciate it, if somebody here wrote it down. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The class of Nagata rings is stable under localization by \[Stacks, [Tag 032U](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/032U)\], and is stable under finite homomorphisms by \[Stacks, [Tag 032T](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/032T)\].